# Cualquier comando que meto en la terminal que empiece con electron-forge me da un mensaje de falta de dependencias

Tags: nodejs, git, electron

Después de haber instalado globalmente  electron-forge con `npm install -g electron-forge` cualquier comando que meto en la terminal relativo a electron-forge me da el siguiente mensaje:

> It looks like you are missing some dependencies you need to get
>   Electron running. Make sure you have git installed and Node.js version
>   6.0.0+

No sé porque me dice que le falta git y Node de la que ambas he instalado tanto local como globalmente las versiones 0.1.5 y 14.0.0 respectivamente.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta está en los comentarios de esta pregunta en inglés:
[Error Message: It looks like you are missing some dependencies you need to get Electron running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408966/error-message-it-looks-like-you-are-missing-some-dependencies-you-need-to-get-e?noredirect=1#comment108636469_61408966)
A pesar del breve comentario que me hace un usuario, resulta muy revelador. 
Deduzco que node o lo que sea que hace correr electron-forge necesita el CLI de git. Entonces voy a la página oficial de git, en mi caso me descargo la versión de git para widows y mientras la instalo en uno de los menus escojo la opción de instalar el CLI, para usar el Git Bash.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]